# c++ import functions from dll - my dll doesn't export lib

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dependencies, shared-libraries

I want to create a dll that exports a function and a struct. I went through the [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) and here is what I have:

Project myDll: the_dll.h

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

typedef struct MyStruct
{
    bool b;
} MYSTRUCTTYPE, *PMYSTRUCTTYPE;
typedef const MYSTRUCTTYPE *MYCSTRUCTTYPE;

MYDLL_API bool dllF();
```

Project myDll: the_dll.cpp

```
#include the_dll.h

bool dllF() { return true };
```

In the Preprocessor definitions of the myDll project, I define `MYDLL_EXPORTS`

In Linker -> Advanced -> Import Library I see `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).lib`

Yet there is no lib generated, only dll and pdb

Intellisense shows `MYDLL_EXPORTS` to be `__declspec(dllexport)` and the `dllimport` portion is grayed out... So I must be exporting...

I have included the dependent header file, and set the additional library directories and additional include directories, as well as dependent libs, in the caller project.  But... in the absence of the lib... 
The project that requires the functions from this dll gives unresolved external symbol error.

How can I make my dll create a lib ? What am I missing ? (Or... how can I use its functions without linking to a lib and include a header ?)

Note: I assume the structs and typedefs do not need to be exported... true ?

**Update**: as I wrote in comment, the project did create a lib when I imported it into a different solution and erased all the debug folders... I have been "Build -> Clean Solution" between tries but I suppose something did not get cleaned ...

So the true reason for not getting a lib created was (my guess) that, while experimenting with the code and before adding the definition for `MYDLL_EXPORTS`, files where created that did not get cleaned... I will always delete the build folders before trying again, in the future.

Comment: `MYDLL_API` should be in front of your `dllF()`, not `MYDLL_EXPORTS`

Comment: oh you are right, sorry, typo, translation from actual code broke down... it is what I have in my code, fixing question... it would not have even built with the MYDLL_EXPORTS... Of course I had MYDLL_API

Comment: Please make sure to not change code when posting. Your *the_dll.cpp* file will not compile. Likewise, the `MYDLL_EXPORTS` in the text probably doesn't expand to what you stated. You probably shouldn't rely on Intellisense either. Have the compiler dump the preprocessed file using the [/P compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx), to see what it really compiles.

Comment: why would the_dll.cpp file not compile ? ... MyDLL_EXPORTS is defined... but does not have a value.......  MYDLL_API expands to  __declspec(dllexport)...... Tried to set preprocess to a file (/P) but I don't know what I am looking for....

Comment: The /P compiler option writes the preprocessed source file to disk. This will tell you whether or not the compiler prepended `__declspec(dllexport)` to your exports. Your *the_dll.cpp* file will not compile as posted. The compiler expects a `}` in place of the second `)`. This is a strong indication that you changed the code in the process of publishing your question.

Comment: Ahhh sorry about the brace... I understant what the option /P does but other than a log file, I did not see anything that I could read... But after recreating my solution (technically ading this project to a different slution) A lib file was created !

Comment: The /P compiler option does not generate a log file. The generated file (with an .i extension) is the actual preprocessed source code that is fed into the compiler. Since your export specifications are generated by the preprocessor I suggested you have a look at the preprocessed file to verify the expected behavior.

Comment: Ah thank you, I assumed that the .i files were binary ! I will always do that in the future when I have trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with a small test project in  VS2013. It produced .lib files for both my DLLs in the Debug directory. This means that if the setup is not screwed up, using default settings you should have implib after building the DLL.

In fact, you need .lib file only if you want to distribute your dll to customers. If you want to use this dll in the same solution by other projects, do the following:

1. Select project where you want to import functions.
2. On the top menu click PROJECT->References....
3. Click button "Add New Reference" at the mid bottom.
4. Select dlls that you want to import from.
5. Close all dialogs with OK.
6. Rebuild your solution.

Structures cannot be exported. They are communicated to other binaries using header files. You can export only function entry points (including class member functions) and static data fields. You should include your header both into your dll code and and all applications that use your DLL. The `#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS` has exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to build, will including the header from the dll be an issue ? It may be what allows me to have the data types created... which is the more important reason I need this dll (consistent data across several other projects)

Comment: @Thalia: This answer doesn't address your question (no .lib file generated). A future visitor is likely disappointed to see this as the accepted answer. I would recommend not accepting it (although you are free to upvote it, since it contains valuable information).

Comment: This answer did give me what I was looking for - though of course if anybody can answer why I did not get a lib file, it will probably be more accurate answer...If I do get such an answer, I will accept it; otherwise, I should change the question I guess

Comment: I added an update... my guess while I did not get a lib while building... This answer gave me an alternative solution, which is great. As well as a good explanation. Thank you all for suggestions